# How do I wear tzitzit out with a tucked-in shirt?

Tags: clothing, tzitzis, how-to

How do I wear *tzitzit* out with a tucked-in shirt? Do I need especially long *tzitzit* or some other trick?

Comment: I think that you answered your own question. You either need long tzitzit or a short shirt. I can't think of any other methodm unless you want to wear the entire tzitzit "beged" over the shirt, which some people do. If that concerns you, you can always wear a jacket over it.

Comment: Would it make life easier for you if the knots were tucked in? (As is brought in halacha that they should be)

Comment: I wear them in, but once I tried to emulate the rabbonim and couldn't get it to work on my tzitzit.

Comment: epic question :)

Answer (score 2):

People normally wear their *tzitzis* out on the sides. Dress shirts are typically shorter there than in the front and back. It should be possible to use normal-length *tzitzis* and a normal-sized shirt together.

Comment: Tragic mistake, as the Tzitzis are supposed to surround you on "all 4 sides"; 2 in front and 2 behind. (At least that's how it was the last time I checked in the Sh. A.)

Comment: @DannySchoemann, most people I see wearing _tzitzis_ out on purpose do so as I described. Perhaps the front ones are slightly front of center and the rear ones are slightly aft.

Comment: @DannySchoemann I noticed early on that I could spot at a glance if a person is a baal tshuva or "frum from birth". BTs wear their tzitzis "spead out" to the "four sides", FFBs wear the right ones together, and the left ones together. :-)

Comment: @NBZ there must be a lot of Ba'alei Teshuvah in Williamsburg Brooklyn then (there are not) as they don't wear them the way you described FFBs as wearing them. Ed. oops, they also wear the beged over the shirt. Never mind...

Comment: @DannySchoemann I believe "surrounded on all 4 sides" is understood to be referring to the garment, not the strings.  Which is best accomplished with each side together, so that the garment completely surrounds your torso.

Comment: @YEZ - that's a peculiar reading of Sh. A. 8:4 - מַחֲזִיר שְׁתֵּי צִיצִיּוֹת לְפָנָיו וּשְׁתַּיִם לַאֲחוֹרָיו כְּדֵי שֶׁיְּהֵא מְסוֹבָב בְּמִצְוֹת.  And the Aruch HaSulchan 8:10 says it's L'Ikuva - you're not Yotzei otherwise - (as per Tur):  והיינו דעיקר מצות ציצית הוא שיהיו שני ציצית לפניו ושנים לאחריו, כדי שיהיה מסובב במצות (טור). ונראה דזהו לעיכובא, דהא ''על ארבע כנפות כסותך'' כתיב, והכנפות הם שתים לפניהם ושתים לאחריהם.

Comment: @DannySchoemann I think that is accomplished by having the shirt go over your shoulders.  I.e. I don't know if you know what a reform/conservative "tallit" looks like, but all four are hanging in the front.  If your בגד goes on like ours does, they are in front and behind and surrounding you, unlike if all four are in front.  I dont think it means "towards the middle of your front and towards the middle of your back" as you would have it.

Comment: @YEZ -  hear you loud and clear, and I understand why you are reading the Poskim that way. But I see no reason to not take them literally. :-) [BTW: The "reform way" also completely  surrounds you with a tallis, in my opinion.]

Answer (score 1):

From personal experience:

I use a Chzon-Ish size begged - about 120cm x 60 cm.

Leave the Tzitzis hanging out where you want them - and then tuck in your shirt around them. The front and back will be tucked in properly, the sides slightly less so.

BTW: According to the Tur (as quoted by the Aruch HaShulchan 8:10) you are not Yotzei the Mitzva of Tzitzis unless you have the strings on all your 4 sides; 2 in front and 2​​​​​ behind. He learns this out from the Pasuk `על ארבע כנפות כסותך`

> והיינו דעיקר מצות ציצית הוא שיהיו שני ציצית לפניו ושנים לאחריו, כדי שיהיה מסובב במצות (טור). ונראה דזהו לעיכובא, דהא ''על ארבע כנפות כסותך'' כתיב, והכנפות הם שתים לפניהם ושתים לאחריהם.

The Shulchan Aruch in 8:4 similarly says:

> מַחֲזִיר שְׁתֵּי  צִיצִיּוֹת לְפָנָיו וּשְׁתַּיִם לַאֲחוֹרָיו כְּדֵי שֶׁיְּהֵא מְסוֹבָב בְּמִצְוֹת.

Comment: And if you wear a jacket, any lack of neatness at the sides will be hidden anyway.  (Thanks -- I'd wondered how people did this.)

Comment: @danny Its interesting that the Arizal would take all four corners and bring them to the front during the shema. Seemingly, at the time when we are mentioning and remembering the mitzvah we should be performing it ideally. Perhaps the Arizal held that it is not , לעיכובה